# Appcelerator Button image not changing in ios

Tags: ios, image, button, appcelerator

Hi i am using a `UIButton` and i want to change its `image` property on `touchstart` and `touchend` events. 
Here is something i am following

```
$.button.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
   e.source.image="image-pressed.png"; 
});

$.button.addEventListener('touchend',function(e){
   e.source.image="image-normal.png"; 
});
```

But i am wondering its not going to happen images are not changing on these events though the event is properly being fired on both touch events.

Kindly guide me how i can place my normal and pressed image for a button.

Thanks.

Comment: Just put debug in  e.source.image="image-pressed.png"; that so you can get idea is this funcation really call or not ?

Comment: if you are talking about touch event, yes its calling properly.but image is not changing very strange.

Comment: 'e' is your button ?

Comment: `e` is instance of event fired from that instance we grab the UI element by `e.source`, i have also tried `$.button.image="image-normal.png";` but same result thats not working.

Comment: put the images in an `images` folder, and change the path to `images/....png` and try again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.button.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
   $.button.image = "image-pressed.png"; 
});

$.button.addEventListener('touchend',function(e){
   $.button.image = "image-normal.png"; 
});
```

It may also happen that your event is bubbling up to any of its parent or parent of parent (if parent has such events attached to it) which means that e.source will not be the button itself. So it's always safe to use **$.Button_ID** to access property like image or title.

Comment: Check my above comments i mentioned this solution is also not working.

Comment: What's your images location? There's nothing tough in this. I tried it here and it works as expected. So you might be missing a very minute point.

Comment: image location is `assets/iphone/image-normal.png` i am using alloy project.